# MySQL #1064 error during table import

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I have been having this reoccurring problem when attempting to import a .sql file into MySQL, Here is what I get 
ERROR 
SQL Query:

```
CREATE TABLE `ADMINS` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_id` varchar(80) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_pw` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `client_school` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `client_expdate` date default '0000-00-00',
  `client_fullname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `webinfo` mediumtext,
  `webinfodate` date default NULL,
  `LastUpdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

MySQL Said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
      `user_activation_key` varchar(60) default NULL,
      `user_email' at line 10
```

Comment: `timestamp` does not have an extra parameter/length.

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps don't have lengths. Change:

```
timestamp(14)
```

to

```
timestamp
```

Comment: Now I Get Mysql said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2' at line 14

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct, as pointed by John you do not need to the length for `timestamp` datatype. In addition `type=myisam` is deprecated and its `engine=myisam` now.

```
CREATE TABLE `ADMINS` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `client_id` varchar(80) NOT NULL default '',
  `client_pw` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `client_school` varchar(16) default NULL,
  `client_expdate` date default '0000-00-00',
  `client_fullname` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `webinfo` mediumtext,
  `webinfodate` date default NULL,
  `LastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) engine=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: I changed all my type= to engine= and now I am getting: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) default NULL,
  `user_email' at line 11

Comment: You are again adding length for `timestamp` it should be `LastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL,` just copy my answer and try it.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you were getting at, I was able to update the file and  it went trough with no errors. Once again thanks! :)